# How to pass ksize in gaussianBlur in Android openCV

Tags: opencv, android

I am trying to implement a simple filtering in an app. Which i have tested using python and works perfectly.

I am trying to achieve following:-

1. Gray scale the image
2. Gaussian blur image with kernal size 5x5
3. Apply adaptive Gaussian Thresholding with disc size 15.

Probably i am asking very silly question but i am unable to pass ksize to GaussianBlur().

My code is:-

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(image, image, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);      
GaussianBlur(image, image,  How to pass size??,0,0);
Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(Blurimage,BinarizedImage,ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,THRESH_BINARY,15);
```

I have tried CV_GAUSSIAN_5x5 , (5,5),Size (5,5), but nothing seem to work. 
It always throws me back to Imhproc.java file, line no 782 with error.

> Error:(782, 54) error: cannot find symbol variable ksize
>   and several other like this.

Everywhere its mentioned to pass the size but i wanst able to find any sample code.

Thank you for help.

Comment: `Imgproc.GaussianBlur(image, image, new Size(5,5));`